# Java Game General Design - Pong

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm making Pong in Java for fun. I just finished Tetris but started off building the game incorrectly, so the poor design followed throughout the program which limited the things I could do.

This time around, I wanted to start off right. I want to:

- Create game following MVC model
- Have sensible class organization and decoupling
- Make proper use of encapsulation
- Separate GUI from game rules

that being said, does my proposed class structure make proper use of classes?

**Main class: extends JFrame** Responsible for adding JPanels to JFrame and initalizing the game

- Adds GamePanel and ScorePanel to JFrame
- Sets their sizes and locations, etc... (Using frame.pack()...)
- Initializes game- `public static void main(String[] args) {...`

**GamePanel class: extends JPanel**: Responsible only for knowing its own boundaries and whether or not an object is breaking those rules...

- paintComponent() draws shapes (Paddles and ball) to screen
- Has boundary and collision (ball collides with paddle) rules
- KeyListeners (not sure if in the correct place)
- Game timer sets beat of the game

**GameRules class:** Responsible for getting data from GamePanel (like, if the ball has collided with paddle), and calculating score and other info based on that...

- Game scoring, game end rules, leveling
- Angles when ball bounces (not sure if in the correct place)

**ScorePanel class:** GUI Responsible for displaying score, level, and other relevant data to player... Will get its data from GameRules class.

- paintComponent() draws scores and other data to screen

**Paddle class: Extends Rectangle2D (AWT)** Responsible for just knowing about its own (x,y) coordinates... having its own color, setting new location

- getX(), getY()
- getColor()
- setLocation(x, y)

**Ball class: Extends Ellipse2D (AWT)** Responsible for just knowing about its own (x,y) coords... just like Paddle

---

**Questions:**

- Unsure where to put math for calculating angles ball should bounce at
- Where should the keyListener go?
- How do I use a "game loop" instead of having the game run through `paintComponent()`?
- Trying to follow MVC model... does this achieve it?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Looks like you may also need a Block class for the blocks that are getting destroyed by the ball. You pretty much have the general idea of MVC. Sometimes the V & C layers get a little grouped up, but your M layer looks great (other than Block class)

Comment: @D.R. I'm making the game `pong`, where you just bounce the ball back and forth. No blocks will be breaking :)

Comment: Oops! Sorry! I was thinking of the wrong game (Breakout). Well then your Model layer looks perfect! And it looks like the V&C layers are pretty decent then too!

Comment: @D.R. Okay, do you know where I should be adding the calculations for the angles and all that math?

Comment: Why is this being voted to close... I think it's a general enough question to where people can benefit from it (MVC, basic OOP design methodologies, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unsure where to put math for calculating angles ball should bounce at

GameRules is as good a class as any.  If your math was more elaborate, you could create a GameMath class.

> Where should the keyListener go?

My first guess would be the GamePanel class.

> How do I use a "game loop" instead of having the game run through paintComponent()?

Your GamePanel paintComponent method is responsible for drawing the current state of the paddles and ball.  It helps if your paddles and ball have their own draw method, so that paintComponent merely calls the paddles and ball draw methods.

Your game loop updates the values in the paddles and ball classes.  You can call paintComponent in it's own loop, to get a steady frame rate, and call your paddles and ball position updates in a different loop.

> Trying to follow MVC model... does this achieve it?

Java Swing can have controller code in the view, in the form of anonymous action classes. I said to put drawing code in the model classes.

While the code isn't necessarily separated, the functionality is.  Drawing code in the model classes is executed by the drawing JPanel.  Control code in the view classes is executed as part of a control action.

Take a look at this article, [Sudoku Solver Swing GUI](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=196), to see how to put together a moderately complicated Swing GUI.  I don't have any examples of a video game to show you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gilbert. I've updated above with a picture of how I think my classes fit into the MVC picture given by Wikipedia. Does it make sense? Thanks

Comment: @Growler: Logically, yes the diagrams make sense.  Physically, you're not going to get a clean separation of Java Swing code into model / view / controller without a lot of unnecessary work.